# A responsive grid (starting at 3 columns, down to 2, then 1) with items of same height?

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design

For example, if I want a grid with 3 columns per row and also want to make sure that each item in the row is of the same height without having to set it specifically (think of `<table>`)...

**Example:**

[image: 3-column grid example]

...I can easily accomplish that with a markup like this (below) and using CSS `display` property with values `table-row` and `table-cell`:

```
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell"></div>
  <div class="table-cell"></div>
  <div class="table-cell"></div>
</div>
```

As for two columns this would do:

```
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell"></div>
  <div class="table-cell"></div>
</div>
```

My question is: how do I create a responsive grid that scales from 3 columns down to 2, and 1, depending on screen size, and also makes sure that all the items in the row are of the same height without me having to set it specifically (as in a `<table>`)?

**NOTE:** It doesn't really matter what CSS properties are used, or how the HTML markup needs to be modified. If you only have an idea, please feel free to share in the comments so that I can do the trials and share back the answer if it works.

***PS:*** I couldn't find a framework that does this. Most scale from 3 to 1, or even if they do 3-2-1 (using `float`), they don't maintain the same height of the items in the row, which is of utmost importance in my design.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by **flexbox**. [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flex)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -o-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -o-box-lines: multiple;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: distribute;
  -moz-box-pack: distribute;
  -o-box-pack: distribute;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container__item {
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -o-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.container__img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
.container__title,
.container__content {
  opacity: 0.99;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=99)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=99);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" class="container__img"/>
    <div class="container__title">Title</div>
    <div class="container__content"> Lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" class="container__img"/>
    <div class="container__title">Title</div>
    <div class="container__content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet molestias excepturi omnis expedita, aliquid laborum in est tempore velit qui aspe illum fugiat enim!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" class="container__img"/>
    <div class="container__title">Title</div>
    <div class="container__content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet molestias excepturi omnis expedita, aliquid laborum in est tempore velit qui aspernatur consectetur consequatur soluta quis alias possimus illum fugiat enim!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" class="container__img"/>
    <div class="container__title">Title</div>
    <div class="container__content"> Lorem </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" class="container__img"/>
    <div class="container__title">Title</div>
    <div class="container__content"> Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```